# Meta-logical terminology

Tags: logic, terminology, model-theory, proof-theory

What do we call a theory $\Gamma$ when...

1. For every sentence $\varphi$, either $\Gamma\vdash\varphi$, or $\Gamma\vdash\neg\varphi$?
2. There is no sentence $\varphi$ such that both $\Gamma\vdash\varphi$ and $\Gamma\vdash\neg\varphi$? ($\Gamma$ is *consistent*?)
3. For every sentence $\varphi$ such that $\Gamma\vdash\varphi$, $\Gamma\vDash\varphi$? ($\Gamma$ is *sound*?)
4. For every sentence $\varphi$ such that $\Gamma\vDash\varphi$, $\Gamma\vdash\varphi$? ($\Gamma$ is *complete*?)
5. For every sentence $\varphi$, either $\Gamma\vDash\varphi$ or $\Gamma\vDash\neg\varphi$?
6. There is no sentence $\varphi$ such that both $\Gamma\vDash\varphi$ and $\Gamma\vDash\neg\varphi$?

Are all these concepts well-defined even for non standard logics, such as many-valued logic, and intuitionistic logic?

Comment: Any decent introductory text on logic will answer questions like this: which texts have you read that have left you puzzled?

Comment: @PeterSmith *A mathematical introduction to logic* by Herbert Enderton.

Answer (score 2):

Briskly:

1. The theory is (syntactically) negation-complete.
2. The theory is syntactically consistent

Soundness and completeness are standardly taken to be features of the deductive apparatus of a theory, of its proof system. So better:

3. If for every $\Gamma, \varphi$, we have $\Gamma\vdash \varphi$ implies $\Gamma\vDash \varphi$, then proof system giving the deducibility relation $\vdash$ is sound.
4. If for every $\Gamma, \varphi$, we have $\Gamma\vDash \varphi$ implies $\Gamma\vdash \varphi$, then proof system giving the deducibility relation $\vdash$ is complete.

Then

5. The theory is semantically negation-complete.
6. The theory is semantically consistent

Comment: Thanks. Since you mentioned in a comment to my original post that any decent introductory text on logic will answer questions as in my original post, would you please refer me to one such specific text that will corroborate your answer?

Comment: Enderton p.131, p. 156 for a start. Though helpful to distinguish completeness of logic and completeness of theory, hence (and commonly) negation-completeness for the second.

Comment: Thanks. The concept defined on p. 156 of Enderton's textbook is that of theory completeness, which I didn't ask about. The concepts defined on p. 131 of Enderton's textbook are those of soundness and completeness of a deductive calculus, and in both cases I correctly specified these terms next to the corresponding question in my original post (though, as you mentioned in your answer, I didn't get their definitions quite right, and thank you for pointing this out). The terminology "negation complete", and the distinction between syntactic and semantic consistency don't appear in Enderton afaik.

Comment: My question had another part, which you didn't address. That of many-valued logic and intuitionistic logic. When talking about many-valued logic, is it customary to talk about logical implication $\Gamma\vDash\varphi$? It so, what does it mean? That $\varphi$ evaluates to *true* under every structure and variable assignment that make all the members of $\Gamma$ *true*? What about intuitionistic logic?

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-manyvalued/ and https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/